# matlab user defined function, get function as an input

Tags: matlab

I got a program which gets x and d as an numeric inputs and f as an arbitrary math function defined by user.
then program should find h which f(x+h*d) is minimum.

how can I store a math function and then use it?

here is an example of what I mean !!

```
function  [] = a(f)
   f(2)
end
```

and user input is like a(X^2)
and the out put should be 4

The question is how can I do such a thing???!!!!

Comment: show us what you have achieved so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function handle to store functions in a variable : http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html

Comment: I got you right, input the anonymous function `@(x)(x.^2)` and you get the desired output.